# Agora implementation with next.js triggers window object error

Tags: next.js, agora.io

I have a next.js application and the current aim is to implement a video call with agora.io. My code looks like this:

```
import React, { useEffect, useState } from "react";
import {
  AgoraVideoPlayer,
  createClient,
  createMicrophoneAndCameraTracks,
  ClientConfig,
} from "agora-rtc-react";

const config = { 
  mode: "rtc",
  codec: "vp8",
};

const appId = ""; // ENTER APP ID HERE
const token = null;

const video = () => {
  const [inCall, setInCall] = useState(false);
  const [channelName, setChannelName] = useState("");

  return (
    <div>
      <h1 className="heading">Agora RTC NG SDK React Wrapper</h1>
      {inCall ? (
        <VideoCall setInCall={setInCall} channelName={channelName} />
      ) : (
        <ChannelForm setInCall={setInCall} setChannelName={setChannelName} />
      )}
    </div>
  );
};

const useClient = createClient(config);
const useMicrophoneAndCameraTracks = createMicrophoneAndCameraTracks();

const VideoCall = (props) => {
  const { setInCall, channelName } = props;
  const [users, setUsers] = useState([]);
  const [start, setStart] = useState(false);
  const client = useClient();
  const { ready, tracks } = useMicrophoneAndCameraTracks();

  useEffect(() => {
    let init = async (name) => {
      client.on("user-published", async (user, mediaType) => {
        await client.subscribe(user, mediaType);
        console.log("subscribe success");
        if (mediaType === "video") {
          setUsers((prevUsers) => {
            return [...prevUsers, user];
          });
        }
        if (mediaType === "audio") {
          user.audioTrack?.play();
        }
      });

      client.on("user-unpublished", (user, type) => {
        console.log("unpublished", user, type);
        if (type === "audio") {
          user.audioTrack?.stop();
        }
        if (type === "video") {
          setUsers((prevUsers) => {
            return prevUsers.filter((User) => User.uid !== user.uid);
          });
        }
      });

      client.on("user-left", (user) => {
        console.log("leaving", user);
        setUsers((prevUsers) => {
          return prevUsers.filter((User) => User.uid !== user.uid);
        });
      });

      await client.join(appId, name, token, null);
      if (tracks) await client.publish([tracks[0], tracks[1]]);
      setStart(true);
    };

    if (ready && tracks) {
      console.log("init ready");
      init(channelName);
    }
  }, [channelName, client, ready, tracks]);

  return (
    <div className="App">
      {ready && tracks && (
        <Controls tracks={tracks} setStart={setStart} setInCall={setInCall} />
      )}
      {start && tracks && <Videos users={users} tracks={tracks} />}
    </div>
  );
};

const Videos = (props) => {
  const { users, tracks } = props;

  return (
    <div>
      <div id="videos">
        <AgoraVideoPlayer
          style={{ height: "95%", width: "95%" }}
          className="vid"
          videoTrack={tracks[1]}
        />
        {users.length > 0 &&
          users.map((user) => {
            if (user.videoTrack) {
              return (
                <AgoraVideoPlayer
                  style={{ height: "95%", width: "95%" }}
                  className="vid"
                  videoTrack={user.videoTrack}
                  key={user.uid}
                />
              );
            } else return null;
          })}
      </div>
    </div>
  );
};

const Controls = (props) => {
  const client = useClient();
  const { tracks, setStart, setInCall } = props;
  const [trackState, setTrackState] = useState({ video: true, audio: true });

  const mute = async (type) => {
    if (type === "audio") {
      await tracks[0].setEnabled(!trackState.audio);
      setTrackState((ps) => {
        return { ...ps, audio: !ps.audio };
      });
    } else if (type === "video") {
      await tracks[1].setEnabled(!trackState.video);
      setTrackState((ps) => {
        return { ...ps, video: !ps.video };
      });
    }
  };

  const leaveChannel = async () => {
    await client.leave();
    client.removeAllListeners();
    tracks[0].close();
    tracks[1].close();
    setStart(false);
    setInCall(false);
  };

  return (
    <div className="controls">
      <p className={trackState.audio ? "on" : ""}
        onClick={() => mute("audio")}>
        {trackState.audio ? "MuteAudio" : "UnmuteAudio"}
      </p>
      <p className={trackState.video ? "on" : ""}
        onClick={() => mute("video")}>
        {trackState.video ? "MuteVideo" : "UnmuteVideo"}
      </p>
      {<p onClick={() => leaveChannel()}>Leave</p>}
    </div>
  );
};

const ChannelForm = (props) => {
  const { setInCall, setChannelName } = props;

  return (
    <form className="join">
      {appId === "" && <p style={{ color: "red" }}>Please enter your Agora App ID in App.tsx and refresh the page</p>}
      <input
        type="text"
        placeholder="Enter Channel Name"
        onChange={(e) => setChannelName(e.target.value)}
      />
      <button onClick={(e) => {
        e.preventDefault();
        setInCall(true);
      }}>
        Join
      </button>
    </form>
  );
};

export default video;
```

When I refresh the page, I see the following error:

```
ReferenceError: window is not defined
```

How do I fix this?

I tried using the [no-ssr](https://www.npmjs.com/package/react-no-ssr) package, but the package itself doesn't install.

Comment: were you able to find a solution? I have same issue